# It's that composer's autoload must have the same document structure？

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoload

the question is when I use symfony 2.7,I upload my own bundle onto composer packagist.
First I try my composer.json like that

```
{
"name" : "funmi/sms-bundle",
"description" : "a develop components from funmitech",
"type" : "symfony-bundle",
"authors" : [{
    "name" : "funmi",
    "email" : "1535399875@qq.com"
}],
"keywords" : [
    "funmi develop"
],
"license" : [
    "MIT"
],
"require" : {
},
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : {
        "Funmi\\SmsBundle" : ""
    }
},
"target-dir" : "",
"repositories" : [{
}],
"extra" : {
    "branch-alias" : {
        "dev-master" : "1.0-dev"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I new Funmi\SmsBundle\FunmiSmsBunle() in appkernel.php it says

> namespace not exist

,than I change the target-dir's value to `/` or `src/` but it still not work.
It only work when I set `target-dir` value to `Funmi\SmsBundle`,now the problem is why i must set like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target-dir` is deprecated, do not use it.

I expect that your bundle class lives in the root directory, correct? That means you need to configure the PSR-4 autoloader:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "Funmi\\SmsBundle\\" : ""
    }
},
```

This configures the autoloader to search for `Funmi\SmsBundle\FunmiSmsBundle` in `/FunmiSmsBundle.php`.

Comment: @LeeDD: feel free to accept this answer if it helped you.